# Bind selected value to Multi Select ListboxFor control using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm facing issues in below scenario, Can any one please guide me.

Scenario:
Get the comma separated Ids from DB which already user entered and split the values then bind values into Multi Select List box control in edit mode.

I tried the following piece of code to achieve it, but its not working for me.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(c => c.ClientDemographicHospitalId, new MultiSelectList(Model.Hospitals, "Value", "Text"), new { ng_model = "hospitalDropdownList", @class = "HospitalListbox", style = "width:65%" })

var lstSelectedIDs = employee.ClientDemographicHospitalId;
var arySelectedID = lstSelectedIDs.split(",");

for (var i = 0; i <= arySelectedID.length; i++) {
    $scope.hospitalDropdownList.append($('<option></option>').val(arySelectedID[i].Value).html(arySelectedID[i].Text));
}
```

Attached the screenshot.

Code:

[image]

Control:

[image]

Comment: Why are you mixing jquery and AngularJS? its  a bad pratice

Answer (score 0):

Given that your input is in the format of `1,2,3,4,5` then you can split the input and use the `ng-options` directive to populate the `<options>` of the `<select>`. Note that your selected option goes into `selectedOption` and `ng-model` is required to go along with `ng-options`.

As a side note:  Don't **ever** mix AngularJS with jQuery. I've heard about cases where the `$` was getting confused between jQuery and AngularJS. Everything can be done in AngularJS without jQuery. (As demonstrated below)

```js
var app = angular.module("MyModule", []);

var MyController = function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "";
  $scope.selectedOption;

  $scope.populateDropDown = function() {
    $scope.allIds = $scope.text.split(",");
  }
}
app.controller(MyController, "[$scope, MyController]");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyModule" ng-controller="MyController">
<input id="ids" type="text" ng-model="text" placeholder="1,2,3,4,5"/>
<select id="list" ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="x for x in allIds">

</select>

<button ng-click="populateDropDown()">Populate</button>
</div>
```